# React map function issue

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am new to React and JS.

I have this piece of code but 'rows' is undefined in console.log output. I am guessing my 
map function is incorrect but I can't figure out why.

```
const stubData = [
  { id: "435879430589041", customer: "jdus", status: "OK" },
  { id: "435879430589042", customer: "jdfr", status: "OK" },
  { id: "435879430589043", customer: "jdnl", status: "pending" },
  { id: "435879430589044", customer: "wsi", status: "config" },
  { id: "435879430589045", customer: "tkmaxx", status: "pending" },
];

const Rows = () => {
  const rows = stubData.map((c,i) => {
    (<tr key={i} value={c}>
      <td>{c.id}</td>
      <td>{c.customer}</td>
      <td>{c.status}</td>
    </tr>)
  }); 
  console.log(rows)
  return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>;
};

const ListIntegrations = props => {
  return (
    <table className="table table-hover">
      <Headers />
      <Rows />
    </table>
  );
```

Headers returns headers perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning anything in the map. Either add a return statement:

```
  const rows = stubData.map((c,i) => {
    return (<tr key={i} value={c}>
      <td>{c.id}</td>
      <td>{c.customer}</td>
      <td>{c.status}</td>
    </tr>)
  });
```

...or delete the curly brackets, thus making the return implicit:

```
  const rows = stubData.map((c,i) => 
    (<tr key={i} value={c}>
      <td>{c.id}</td>
      <td>{c.customer}</td>
      <td>{c.status}</td>
    </tr>)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning from map

```
stubData.map((c,i) => {
    (<tr key={i} value={c}>
      <td>{c.id}</td>
      <td>{c.customer}</td>
      <td>{c.status}</td>
    </tr>)
  });
```

change it as

```
stubData.map((c,i) => {
    return (<tr key={i} value={c}>
      <td>{c.id}</td>
      <td>{c.customer}</td>
      <td>{c.status}</td>
    </tr>)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using arrow function as a callback to map.
If you don't have curly braces {} arrow function implicitly returns

```
const rows = stubData.map((c,i) => 
(<tr key={i} value={c}>
  <td>{c.id}</td>
  <td>{c.customer}</td>
  <td>{c.status}</td>
</tr>)
);
```

Or if you use curly braces you need to return explicitly

```
const rows = stubData.map((c,i) => {
return
(<tr key={i} value={c}>
  <td>{c.id}</td>
  <td>{c.customer}</td>
  <td>{c.status}</td>
</tr>)
});
```